# how to write a char array "char *buff[]" to a FILE in c

Tags: c, file, file-io, file-handling

satuation is ..... i've stored many mac addresses (one by one) in the buffer(*buff[]), now i want to extract the MAC addresses one by one and write it to a FILE seperated by COMMA  in c.

HELP!!!
THNXXX!!

Comment: As usual: what have you tried already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they're strings, you can just use something like:

```
FILE *fout = fopen ("output.txt", "w");
if (fout != NULL) {
    char *sep = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof (buff) / sizeof(*buff); i++) {
        fprintf (fout, "%s%s", sep, buff[i]);
        sep = ",";
    }
    fclose (fout);
}
```

If they're *not* strings, you should probably specify the data in greater detail. In any case, the logic is the same, the only thing that will change is the way in which you output the MAC address.

And if the array isn't full, then make sure you use a count variable to control the loop rather than the array size.

Comment: You are assuming that "buff" is statically allocated, ie buff is char* buff[10]. If "buff" instead happens to be the parameter of a function, ie void func (char* buff[]); then your code won't work. This isn't made clear by the original post. Also, you are writing a C++ declaration of "i" inside the loop.

Comment: Yes, I made assumptions, it was necessary due to the lack of full details in the question - that's exactly why I said "use something _like_  ". But you should be aware that the `int` inside `for` loop is not just a C++ feature, C99 has it also.